# Connecting two ESXi servers via LAN

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, routing

i have an issue with configuring two ESXi servers to communicate with each other. My configuration looks like this: 2 ESXi servers with 4-4 Ethernet ports. ETH01 on each server is used for internet (external) connection, and ETH04 ports are used to connect the servers together.

The IP configuration looks like this:
ESXi1
ETH1: extIP
ETH4: 192.168.25.240

ESXi2
ETH1: extIP
ETH4: 192.168.25.241

I have a VPN server running on ESXi2. By connecting externally to that VPN server, i would like to be able to reach both ESXi servers and VMs running on them, but I can reach only ESXi2 LAN port (192.168.25.241) and VMs running on that server - not the second server. When trying to ping 192.168.25.240 - it is not working. I have tried to ping .240 straight from ESXi SSH, but it is also down.

The routing tables have on Both VM servers:
192.168.25.0   255.255.255.0  0.0.0.0         vmk1       MANUAL

I have created also a virtual switches on both servers sitting on ETH4, which is configured for the VMs LAN ports.

So my main issue is - traffic is not going through ETH04 between the two servers.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if your ETH04 port link is up. If you are inter-connecting your servers directly(not via switch), you need to use cross cable.

Comment: Thank you very much - this was the best answer. I was fiddling with it and finally found the issue: I had multiple connections in the back of the servers. But the numbering on the ethernet ports at the back of the server was wrong compared to numbering in vmware (vmnics). Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use vmkping from each server to attempt to ping the other.  The ESXi firewall in the remote host may also be blocking this traffic, but doubtful.

```
vmkping 192.168.25.240
```

[VMware KB1003728 describes using this tool in more detail.](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003728)

Edited to show command and link to vmware docs.

Comment: You could improve your post by showing an example usage of `vmkping`, and perhaps by explaining why that tool could help the OP solve their issue.

Comment: @Castaglia, see the above edit.  Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: Thank you very much with the help. I was fiddling with it and finally found the issue: I had multiple connections in the back of the servers. But the numbering on the ethernet ports at the back of the server was wrong compared to numbering in vmware (vmnics). Thank you for the help :)